# delete a selected book(book_title, author, price, rent and category) using select option in front of books

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

**Database**
[image: Database]

I would like to delete row by clicking "delete" button

[image: I would like to delete row by clicking "delete" button]

CODE UNDER BOOK DETAILS(bookdetails.php):

```
<?php

        <body>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="10">BOOK DETAILS</th>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <th>Book_title</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Rent</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    include('connection.php');
                    $y=mysql_query("select * from `addbooks`");
                    while($z=mysql_fetch_array($y)){ ?>
                            <td align="center" ><a href="deletebooksdb.php" class="delete">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                } ?>
            </table>
```

Comment: Please post your code as text and not pictures.

Comment: Please read the [ask], according to @George's comment. Then please stop using myql*-functions and use mysqli or PDO instead. Mysql functions are deprecated!

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely not the right way to ask a question as people have pointed out to you in comments directly under the post. But to solve your problem

Update your code in `bookdetails.php` to show

```
               <?php
                    include('connection.php');
                    $y=mysql_query("select * from `addbooks`");
                    while($z=mysql_fetch_array($y)){
                            echo '<td align="center" ><a href="deletebooksdb.php?id='.$z['id'].'" class="delete">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>';

                } ?>
```

Then in your `deletebooksdb.php` file, add

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

then update your query to

```
$query = mysql_query("delete from `addbooks` WHERE id = $id");
```

This would solve your problem but I must mention to you that this is not the safest way to go. There are multiple measures you need to address including the need to validate your input properly, use `mysqli` etc.

But for now, that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you use Mysqli rather than Mysql.

Example code, Not formatted for your table:

```
 <?php
    include('connection.php');
    $y=mysql_query("select * from `addbooks`");
    while($z=mysql_fetch_array($y)){
     echo '<a href="deletebooksdb.php?id=' . $z['id'] . '" class="delete">Delete</a>
    }
 ?>
```

deletebooksdb.php

```
<?php
  include('connection.php');
  $id =  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
  $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `addbooks` WHERE id=$id");
?>
```